# pdf: What is the distribution of aX when X ~ Binomial / Gaussian

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

**Question**

When $X$ is distributed as binomial or Gaussian, is $aX$ equivalent to some famous distribution? Here, $a$ is a real and positive number.

**Background**

I know a general formula giving $aX$'s distribution as $\frac{1}{|a|}f(\frac xa)$. ($f$ means the distribution of $X$)

I think $aX$ is also Gaussian if $X \sim Gaussian$. But, I'm not sure and want to know the case of Binomial.

Comment: Let $X$ be binom with $(p,n)$ and $a$ is real, then $a X$ takes values of $1/a, 2/a, ... , n/a$ which are possibly not discrete values. $aX$ has a properly defined distribution which is not among the well-known distributions. The normal case is obvious (as shown below).

Comment: The normal case can be shown by using the uniqueness of moment generating functions, writing out the definition of the MGF of $aX$ (using the law of the unconscious statistician) and completing the square.

Comment: @JessicaK thank you. MGF is a really convenient tool.

Comment: Thank you guys. I put a new question deeply related to this. Check it out as well :) http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1254069/how-to-get-the-value-of-scaled-binomial-distribution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that $aX$ is also Gaussian if $X \sim \text{Gaussian}$, with mean $a\mu$ and variance $a^2\sigma^2$.

As far as I am aware there is not a binomial equivalent in terms of the name, but there is the same scaling of mean and variance.