# How to get the value of 'scaled' binomial distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

[People kindly told me](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1253951/pdf-what-is-the-distribution-of-ax-when-x-binomial-gaussian) that there is not a equivalent popular distribution for $aX$ when $X$ is distributed as Binomial, but it is just a 'scaled' distribution. Here, $a$ is a positive constant.

**Question**

How to get the value of 'scaled' binomial distribution? Do I need to use $\Gamma$ function? A simpler way is appreciated.

To be more precise, I want to calculate $$g(x) = \frac{1}{|a|}f(\frac xa) = {n \choose x/a} p^{\frac xa} (1-p)^{(n-\frac xa)},$$ where $f(x)$ is $B(n,p)$ and $a$ is positive constant.

What is the simplest way to calculate $g(x)$?

**Background**

I'm considering this question under the same condition with this question, where $X$ is distributed as $Binomial$ and I want to know the distribution of $aX$. $a$ is a real and positive number.

I know
$aX \sim \frac{1}{|a|}f(\frac xa)$ ($f$ means the distribution of $X$),so I tried to calculate the probability of $aX$ by $\frac{1}{|a|}f(\frac xa) = {n \choose x/a} p^{\frac ax} (1-p)^{(n-\frac xa)}$. But, this was not easy for me because $x/a$ is not a integer.

I think with $\Gamma$ function $nCr$ can be calculated for any  real number $r (< n)$. But is there any straightforward way to calculate 'scaled' binomial distribution?

Comment: You may want to look at the beta function—http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function—as it provides a way to extend the binomial distribution to real values.  (It's indicated near the end of the "Properties" section.)

Comment: So, yes, you will need to use the gamma function.  I suspect there's no way around it for your application.

Comment: @BrianTung thank you. This is what I'm looking for. If you replace your comment to an answer, I would give a check mark :)

Comment: Thanks for your kind offer!  But I'd probably only move it to an answer if you're looking to give out a checkmark.  (I don't remember if you get any points for doing that.)  Otherwise, if my contribution is merely a link to another page, I generally leave it in a comment.  If it helped you out, that's good enough for me.

Comment: @rkjt50r983, your scale function is not a density function because it does not normalise to 1. I think you consider that as a critical issue as well.

Answer (score 2):

For a random variable $X$ of binomial distribution of parameters $n,p$ the possible values taken are $0,1,2, \cdots, n$ with probabilities$$P(X=k)={n \choose k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}.$$
If $a$ is a real constant and $Y=aX$ then the valueas taken by $Y$ are $1a,2a,\cdots , na$ with probabilities $$P(Y=ak)=P(X=k).$$
I don't know if this answers the question.

**EDITED**

Perhaps, the reason of confusion is that there is no pdf. The cdf is
$$F_Y(x)=P(aX<x)=P\left(X<\frac{x}{a}\right)=F_X\left(\frac{x}{a}\right).$$

If the derivative existed then one could get a formula similar to what you quoted for the Gaussian distribution.

Comment: thank you, but I think it is necessary to calculate ${n \choose k/a}p^{k/a}(1-p)^{n-k/a}.$. More specifically, how do I define and calculate ${n \choose k/a}$?

Comment: @rkjt50r938, The probabilities that $Y=ai$ are given. What else would want anybody know? The is no pdf in this case. Perhaps you want see the form of the cdf??

Comment: @rkjt50r938: I've edited my answer.