# How to scale a negative binomial distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions, negative-binomial

I posted a variation of this question on [Cross-validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/448045/negative-binomial-regression-effect-of-scaling-input-data-on-models-output), but did not get any answer, so I hope someone can help me over here.

A bit of background first. I have implemented a neural network for time series forecasting. The network outputs the parameters (mean $\mu$ and dispersion $\theta$) of a negative binomial distribution

$$\Pr(X = x) = \binom{x+\theta-1}{x} \left(\frac{\mu}{\theta + \mu}\right)^\theta \left(\frac{\theta}{\theta + \mu}\right)^x$$

To ease with model training, I want to scale the input data (i.e., divide by $k$ the past timesteps fed to the network) and then remove the scaling effect on the predicted distribution parameters. If my network was outputting the mean and variance of a Gaussian distribution, I would multiply the predicted mean and variance by $k$ and $k^2$, respectively. However, I am not sure how to do this for a negative binomial.

After running some experiments, the way to do it that I came up with (see the [Cross-validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/448045/negative-binomial-regression-effect-of-scaling-input-data-on-models-output) question) does not seem right. In the DeepAR [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.04110) (p. 5), the authors multiply the mean and dispersion by $k$ and $\sqrt{k}$, respectively. But I do not know where multiplying the dispersion by $\sqrt{k}$ comes from.

Moreover, after reading this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1254069/how-to-get-the-value-of-scaled-binomial-distribution) I wonder if there is actually a solution to what I want to do.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: If you divide each element of a NB sample by the mean $k$, then it's no longer a NB distribution, if only because the values are not all integers. So there is no point trying to fit NB parameters to the scaled sample.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Yes, I realised about that and I agree. That is also why I say I do not know what the authors of the DeepAR paper are doing.

Comment: It looks like negative binomial regression. You may have a look [here](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/negative-binomial-regression/) or at [this book](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/negative-binomial-regression/12D6281A46B9A980DC6021080C9419E7). However, there are also autoregressive components and neural network stuff, so I'm not sure how to address this.

Comment: Thanks @Jean-ClaudeArbaut. I am indeed dealing with negative binomial regression, but as you also say, I am doing it with a neural network. I had already seen that book you mention, but in "traditional" neg-binomial regression scaling the input data does not seem to be necessary, so I could not find any info about that.

Comment: I was also wondering about this after reading the DeepAR paper. By the way, in the paper the dispersion is multiplied by $\frac{1}{\sqrt k}$, not $\sqrt k$. Wikipedia states that the Negative Binomial distribution [has an extension to a real-valued r](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution#Extension_to_real-valued_r), by writing the combinations with the Gamma function.